# Class moderncv error: undefined control sequence \gitlabsocialsymbol

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I'm having problems to display the favicon for Gitlab in my `moderncv` project. I think it has to do with my installation of `moderncv`.

I'm on a Ubuntu machine and first I installed `texlive-latex-extra`.

After some googling I found out that the `moderncv` version in TeX Live is out of date. So I cloned the `moderncv` git repo and put it into `/home/{user}/texmf/tex/latex/moderncv`.

```
$ kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
/home/{user}/texmf
```

So I would think that the newer version of `moderncv` in my home folder has precedence. But apparently this is not the case.

When I try to compile the example template from `moderncv`

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{10cm}            % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[xing]{john\_doe}                           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[skype]{jdoe}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
%\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                              % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\gitlabsocialsymbol ->{\small \faGitlab
```

If it makes any difference I'm using VS Code with the LaTeX Workshop plugin. I think the compiler it is using is `latexmk`.

If I take out the line `social[gitlab]{jdoe}` everything works fine.

Would be much appreciated if anyone could help me sort out these issues. Happy to provide any additional info that is needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange. If you had to manually update `moerncv`, most likely the `fontawesome` package is out of date too. Sadly, manually updating `fontawesome` is a bit more advanced and might require even more updates of other packages. So I would recommend replacing the whole TeX Live version packaged for Ubuntu with an up-to-date version of TeX Live. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1) for details how to install "vanilla" TeX Live on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes I think you are right in regards to fontawesome. I was using a version from 2015. I just tried to update by downloading a package from ctan and putting the files in my local texmf folder. It does compile now with the Gitlab favicon but the icons are all wrong now and I get warnings that fonts were substitued. I guess I will try your way and install up-to-date TeX Live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not tell us which versions of `modencv` and `fontawesome` you use.

At last ubuntu (and debian) installed an outdated version of TeX Live.  Better is to use the original TeX Live you can install following  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

If you want to try only installation of `fontawesome` on Ubuntu, use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Make sure that the FNDB is updated and that all font maps are loaded (I do not use ubuntu, I do not know how that is done with that OS).

After installing TeX Live new you lost your manualy updated `moderncv`. Therefore it is better to add the needed changes to `moderncv` into the preamble of your cv.

Please see the following code (I marked all important code changings with `<=========`; Please see that I changed `http` in the links to the today used and more secure `https`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% makes a https hyperlink
% usage: \httpslink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{% <=======================================
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}    {{\small\faXing}~} % <===============
\newcommand*{\gitlabsocialsymbol}  {{\small\faGitlab}~} % <=============
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}   {{\small\faSkype}~} % <==============

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}} {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{xing}}    {\collectionadd[xing]{socials}    {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.xing.com/profile/#3}}}{}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}     {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}      {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{gitlab}}  {\collectionadd[gitlab]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.gitlab.com/#3}}}      {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{skype}}   {\collectionadd[skype]{socials}   {#3}}                                            {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother % <========================================================


% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[xing]{john\_doe} % <============================================
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}
\social[skype]{jdoe} % <================================================
\extrainfo{additional information}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt} 


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting footer]

This is compiled with current class `moderncv` 2.0.0 (that one from ctan, not from the github!), current fontawesome `fontawesome.sty 2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons` and current MiKTeX `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit)`.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now after I installed the newest version of `texlive` and `fontawesome`. Even without your tweaks. Interestingly the Gitlab social symbol is not working when I use classic style for `moderncv` instead of casual. I guess it is because `moderncv` uses different icons for the classic style. Can you confirm that the Gitlab icon does work for you in classic style? Also I prefer the casual symbols anyway, so is there a simple way to switch between them or do I have to redefine them like you did?

Comment: @c_student in `classic` style the command `\moderncvicons{marvosym}` is used. You can use fontawesome with adding `\moderncvicons{awesome}` before `\begin{document}` and after `\moderncvstyle{classic}` ...

Comment: I know the topic is a bit older, but with a 1:1 copy in texmaker (UTF-8) I still get 3 errors which I can not get solved:

! LaTeX Error: Command \httpslink already defined.

! LaTeX Error: Command \xingsocialsymbol already defined.

the same for \gitlabsocialsymbol and \skypesocialsymbol


and 2nd question:
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
i am normal in iso-8859-15 for the test i just created a new utf-8 document now. Can this be easily converted later? I could not figure it out from some sources.

Comment: @protter meanwhile exists version 2.1 of class moderncv with included command \httpslink and included xing and skype etc symbols. Check the logfile to confirm you are using version 2.1. Then comment my additions in the mwe above and try again. If you still have errors please ask a new question with your current code resulting in errors ...