# Undefined Control Sequence in Overleaf while using social icons

Tags: overleaf, moderncv, fontawesome

I am getting this error "Undefined control sequence" in overleaf when I inserted this code - `\social[linkedin]{www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxx}` and `\social[github]{www.github.com/xxxxx}`. I tried solutions given on some previously asked questions[such as on these sites - [A1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338657/how-to-include-socials-icons-like-github-and-linkedin-in-moderncv), [A2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477882/class-moderncv-error-undefined-control-sequence-gitlabsocialsymbol) ] related to this issue, however, they do not seem to work for me.

It'd be of great help if some could suggest any alternate solutions [other than "uploading images of the logos" solution]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. In order to help you we need to have a Minimal Working Example (MWE). It's a document that starts with `\documentclass{` and ends with `\end{document}` that recreates your problem. An example for why we need that: The code you are trying to use is from moderncv class? Are you using it in the moderncv class or in a different class? The moderncv class requires the package `fontawesome5` that package cannot be used with `fontawseome`.  That class also defines a command `\social` that uses font awsome icons. Do you have that command defined?

Comment: the error message would say _which_ command is undefined but you have not shown the message and not provided any code to show the error, so hard to help.